Text overlapping over the Toolbar
[I Wrote my first program in jetpack compose and I face this problem that a simple text after putting in a column{} or in a row{} it begins from the toolbar of the emulator means the text gets overlapped behind the toolbar.]
check the image 
I tried to resolve the problem from my research but couldn't found anything.

Disable EdgeToEdge support, to do so remove
enableEdgeToEdge()

from the onCreate method the activity.
